# Issue for autocomplete from Db

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Actually, I have done location search for normal HTML input type in my site (not functionality wise), I have stored locations name in database, if I search any location it should come jQuery autocomplete also and if I click a bangalore means bangalore records will open, fetching from database how will fix and please help me anyone.

Here my HTML markup:

```
<div class="form-group keyword">
   <input type="text" id="location" placeholder="Search by location" name="location" list="locations" class="searchlocation" />      
</div>
```

Here my PHP code:

```
<?php
    require_once ('config.php');

    $q=$_REQUEST["q"]; 
    $sql="SELECT `pg_address` FROM `tbl_master_property` WHERE pg_address LIKE '%$q%'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $json=array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $data[] = $row['pg_address'];
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Ajax and jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

        $(function() {
            $( "#location" ).autocomplete({
                source: function( request, response ) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "locationsearch.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            q: request.term
                        },
                        success: function( data ) {
                            response( data );
                        }
                    });
                },
            });
        });     
</script>
```

Comment: whats the code for "locationsearch.php" ?

Comment: Please check above my php code

Comment: Is there any error? and have your tried? `response($.parseJSON( data ));`? Try to look at the network tab in the developer tools and see if you get the correct response..

Comment: aren't mysql_* functions deprecated yet?

Comment: Hi Shadow Fiend,,,, i tried your comment but the response out put is showing error like :  <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: q in <b>C:\xampp\www\htdocs\autocomplete\search.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />

Comment: Hi all,   i have fixed that issue but when ever i search my location that location related records not display how will display this please help and give me idea